# PHPMailer Email going to Gmail Promotions Tab, not Inbox, why?

Tags: smtp, gmail, phpmailer, yahoo

Have set up a system for a Website to send mails using PHPMailer to company staffs, but E-mails are Not going to the Inbox for those using Gmail, it's getting Stored in the Promotions-TAB...

The mails are being sent using a Yahoo Account.

Please see my Codes

```
    require_once('pm/PHPMailerAutoload.php');   

        $username ="xxxxxxxs@yahoo.com";
        $password="pwdxxxx";

        $senderName ="COMPANY NAME HERE";
        $mail = new PHPMailer();


        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
        $mail->Host       = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com";
        $mail->Port       = 587;
        $mail->Username   = $username;
        $mail->Password   = $password;
        $mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;

        // Build the message
        $mail->Subject = 'Urgent Meeting at the Director's Officie';

        $mail->From = $username;
        $mail->FromName = $senderName;
        $mail->AddReplyTo('xxxxx@gmail.com','COMPANY NAME HERE');

            $mail->AddAddress($user_data["Email_Add"],$user_data["Staff_Name"]);
        /*
        ooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
        ooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
        0000---MESSAGE-STARTS--oooo
        ooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
        ooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
        */

        $mail->msgHTML('

        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />


<title>Urgent Meeting at the Director's Office</title>


</head>

    <body>


         <div style="width:100%;" align="center">
              There is an Urgent meeting at the Director's Office. All stuffs MUST be there. in 30Mins
         </div>


    </body>
    </html>

    ');


    /*
        ooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
        ooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
        0000---MESSAGE-ENDS-ooooooo
        ooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
        ooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
        */

        if(!$mail->Send()) {

    echo 'Failed';
    }

        else {
            echo 'Sent well';

        }


        $mail->SmtpClose();
```

What can I do to have the received in the inbox?... Please Help thanx

Comment: well more than likely this is just a gmail issue. if they receive similar looking emails from the same address to their system, they might just flag it this way.

Comment: is there any work around this??... cz friends send eachother Emails Frequently with Similar lookings from same Addresses but they aren't flagged that way.... is there something that can be done?

Comment: i am just suggesting a possible answer to why ... you would have to look into it yourself. what i meant by similar is that the email you are sending to multiple people, is identical accept for the TO field, so gmail may think it is a mass mailing.

Comment: The reason why they complained is, usually when the Secretary sends Mass Emails to Each Staff, it is received in the Inbox, She Frequently Sends Mails to Each Staff in the TO: and CC and BCC, using her Yahoo Acc to Gmail INBOX. But when She tried the Acc that I set up with PHPMailer, Emails started going to the Promotion Tab... See my code

Comment: okay .. it isnt your code ... that account must be flagged

Comment: I tried 5 different Accounts. When I log into Yahoo, then I send the message from Yahoo, it Goes to the GMAIL Inbox. but when I use PHPMailer, it Goes to Promotions...

Comment: well you are going to have to look at the email headers then. did you try searching google for why they do this ?

Comment: I have actually posted the Same Question there as well. See Link: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/gmail/report-an-issue/reading-and-receiving-messages/mozilla-firefox/9NNQ2_U0Ku0

Comment: Look this aswer : https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-get-Gmail-to-stop-filtering-my-emails-as-promotions